# Problems trying to use multiple CTEs in one SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not quite sure how to form this in the right way. I need to insert multiple companies. Each CTE here inserts records into a few company tables.

Initially I was running just one CTE that looked like this and worked fine:

```
WITH newCompany AS 
(
    INSERT INTO company (company_id, company_name)
    VALUES (1, 'CompanyA')
    RETURNING company_id, company_name
),
newProfile AS 
(
    INSERT INTO companyProfile (company_id, profile_header_image_url)
        SELECT company_id, 'https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxx/assets/xxxx/header.jpg' 
        FROM newCompany
    RETURNING profile_id, profile_header_image_url
),
newCompanyProfile AS 
(
    INSERT INTO company_profile (company_id, profile_id)
        SELECT c.company_id, p.profile_id 
        FROM newCompany c, newProfile p
)
SELECT
    c.company_id,
    c.company_name,
    p.profile_id,
    p.profile_header_image_url
FROM 
    newCompany c, newProfile p
```

But now I'm trying to add multiple CTEs (one for each company). so I tried to add RECURSIVE and tried to surround each CTE with `()` and add a comma between CTEs, but I'm just not there yet:

```
--CTE #1
WITH RECURSIVE newCompany AS ((
    insert into company (company_id,company_name)
    values(1, 'CompanyA')
    returning company_id, company_name
),
newProfile AS (
    insert into companyProfile (company_id, profile_header_image_url)
    SELECT company_id, 'https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxx/assets/xxxx/header.jpg' from newCompany
    returning profile_id, profile_header_image_url
),
newCompanyProfile AS (
    insert into company_profile (company_id, profile_id)
    SELECT c.company_id, p.profile_id from newCompany c, newProfile p
)
SELECT
    c.company_id,
    c.company_name,
    p.profile_id,
    p.profile_header_image_url
FROM newCompany c, newProfile p),

--CTE #2
newCompany AS ((
    insert into company (company_id,company_name)
    values(2, 'CompanyB')
    returning company_id, company_name
),
newProfile AS (
    insert into companyProfile (company_id, profile_header_image_url)
    SELECT company_id, 'https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxx/assets/xxxx/header.jpg' from newCompany
    returning profile_id, profile_header_image_url
),
newCompanyProfile AS (
    insert into company_profile (company_id, profile_id)
    SELECT c.company_id, p.profile_id from newCompany c, newProfile p
)
SELECT
    c.company_id,
    c.company_name,
    p.profile_id,
    p.profile_header_image_url
FROM newCompany c, newProfile p)
```

Error: `query error error: syntax error at or near "insert"`

Comment: CTE is a table expression. It must return a table (relation). No DML is allowed in the CTE body but SELECT.

Comment: "Initially I was running just one CTE that looked like this and worked fine" => this statement is NOT true....

Comment: I can't fathom what you expect to happen with a select from a CTE that's an *update*, where the CTE must *return* a result set. I would start by [reading the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) for CTEs and then some tutorials.

Comment: You can do some of what you ask, but do you really want a `companyProfile` to use `company_id` as the primary key?  If so, why would you want a `company_profile` table if the relationship is `one to one`?  I can show you an example even with the `company_profile` table.  But I would need to make assumptions about detail you haven't provided.

Comment: PostgreSQL does allow `DML` such as `INSERT ... RETURNING ...` in a CTE term.  It's odd, but supported.  But it currently requires anything like `INSERT` to be at a top-level `WITH clause` term.

Comment: I've got a list of companies and each company has a header url (every url is different).  So I need to get back the same ID I inserted in order to insert a companyProfile record right after for each company I am adding to my DB.  I figured a CTE would be a nice syntax for inserting each new company / companyProfile pair

Comment: If you are just using the company_id for both tables in a `one to one` relationship, there's really no need for the mapping table `company_profile`, as I mentioned earlier.  Unless you need more than one company per profile and more than one profile per company, that mapping table can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Updated with the new requirement (different url per company).  There's no need for a separate statement per company.

Here's an example of inserting company, profile, and company_profile (for more than one `company`, with separate urls for each company) all in one expression with CTE terms.

There doesn't seem to be a reason for the mapping table `company_profile` if the relationship is `one to one`.  I left that in anyway.

The test case:

[Working Test Case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9f72d6dbcd47faf8e3731b5222e3675d)

I'm not endorsing this approach.

One assumption is `company_id` and `profile_id` is the same for related rows. The question seems to make that assumption too:

```
WITH args (company_id, company_name, url) AS (
         VALUES (1, 'CompanyA', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxx/assets/xxxx/header.jpg')
              , (2, 'CompanyB', 'https://address/xxxx/assets/xxxx/header2.jpg')
     )
   , newCompany AS (
    INSERT INTO company (company_id, company_name)
    SELECT company_id, company_name FROM args
    RETURNING company_id, company_name
),
newProfile (profile_id, profile_header_image_url) AS 
(
    INSERT INTO companyProfile (profile_id, profile_header_image_url)
        SELECT company_id, url
        FROM args
    RETURNING profile_id, profile_header_image_url
),
newCompanyProfile (company_id, profile_id) AS 
(
    INSERT INTO company_profile (company_id, profile_id)
        SELECT c.company_id, p.profile_id 
        FROM newCompany c
        JOIN newProfile p
          ON c.company_id = p.profile_id
    RETURNING company_id, profile_id
)
SELECT
    c.company_id,
    c.company_name,
    p.profile_id,
    p.profile_header_image_url
  FROM newCompany      c
  JOIN newCompanyProfile cp
    ON c.company_id = cp.company_id
  JOIN newProfile      p
    ON p.profile_id = cp.profile_id
;

SELECT * FROM company;
SELECT * FROM company_profile;
SELECT * FROM companyProfile;
```

Result:

[image: Updated result]

Comment: really appreciate it...learned a lot here thank you.

Comment: every company has a different profile_header_image_url though. I put xxx to hide some proprietary stuff for my site, but every company has a different header url for an image

Comment: @PositiveGuy I was just following your original question, which had the same URL per company.  The above has been updated to add a URL per company, all in one statement.  No need to duplicate this per company.

Comment: @PositiveGuy You didn't provide the schema (create table statements), so I just created what was necessary.  Adding company_id in the companyProfile table is fine.  It just wasn't necessary to address the original requirement, since the relationship seemed to be `one to one`.  All this can be adjusted too.  There are still some other issues in your SQL, which I had corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all I needed to separate this was a `;`.  So this ended up working

```
WITH newCompany AS (
    insert into company (company_id,company_name)
    values(1, 'CompanyA')
    returning company_id, company_name
),
newProfile AS (
    insert into companyProfile (company_id, profile_header_image_url)
    SELECT company_id, 'https://storage.googleapis.com/aaaaa/assets/aaaaa/header.jpg' from newCompany
    returning profile_id, profile_header_image_url
),
newCompanyProfile AS (
    insert into company_profile (company_id, profile_id)
    SELECT c.company_id, p.profile_id from newCompany c, newProfile p
)
SELECT
    c.company_id,
    c.company_name,
    p.profile_id,
    p.profile_header_image_url
FROM newCompany c, newProfile p;

WITH newCompany AS (
    insert into company (company_id,company_name)
    values(2, 'CompanyB')
    returning company_id, company_name
),
newProfile AS (
    insert into companyProfile (company_id, profile_header_image_url)
    SELECT company_id, 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bbbbb/assets/bbbbb/header.jpg' from newCompany
    returning profile_id, profile_header_image_url
),
newCompanyProfile AS (
    insert into company_profile (company_id, profile_id)
    SELECT c.company_id, p.profile_id from newCompany c, newProfile p
)
SELECT
    c.company_id,
    c.company_name,
    p.profile_id,
    p.profile_header_image_url
FROM newCompany c, newProfile p;
```